# How can i normalize this data on python? And how can i make the calculations of this on paper?

Tags: python, normalize

I have to normalize the following data:

```
price = [360, 159, 266, 259]
vol = [60, 99, 77, 31]
```

So I need to now the average of both:

```
price_avg =  sum(price)/len(price)

vol_avg =  sum(vol)/len(vol)
```

What do I need to do next?
And how can I make the calculations of this on paper?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you're asking, but if it's how to calculate the average of a list of numbers on paper - it's off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization usually means: substract from each data point the data mean and divide by the standard deviation.

In Python you should use `numpy` for that.

```
import numpy as np
price = np.array([360, 159, 266, 259])
price_mean = np.mean(price)
price_std = np.std(price)
price_normalized = (prize - price_mean) / price_std
```

Or single line:

```
price_normalized = (prize - np.mean(price)) / np.std(price)
```